# Trying to set width of a textView inside getView() of ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View V = convertView;

        if(V == null){
            LayoutInflater vi =
                    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            V = vi.inflate(R.layout.barlist_row, null);

        }

        BarListItem ci = mBarList.get(position);
        double likes_cnt = ci.getLikes();
        double dislikes_cnt = ci.getDislikes();

        TextView likes = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.prg_likes);
        TextView dislikes = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.prg_dislikes);
        TextView title = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        TextView distance = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.txt_distance);

        if(likes_cnt > dislikes_cnt){
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            likes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
            px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150*((float)ci.getDislikes()/(float)ci.getLikes()), r.getDisplayMetrics());
            dislikes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
        }else{
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            dislikes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
            px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,150*((float)ci.getLikes()/(float)ci.getDislikes()), r.getDisplayMetrics());
            likes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
        }

        title.setText(ci.getTitle());
        likes.setText(" " + String.valueOf(ci.getLikes()));
        dislikes.setText(" " + String.valueOf(ci.getDislikes()));
        distance.setText(String.valueOf(ci.getDistance()) + " miles");

        return V;
    }
```

So for this app I have made a custom List Adapter. Everything is working quite well, but the width of the textView's inside of each row of my listView are not correct.

The point of these textViews is to illustrate with image and text, the likes and dislikes count for a bar. I cannot insert an image into the question but I will try to explain. I am working with 150 dp. So if a bar has one like and 0 dislikes, it should look like this

likes    --------------
dislikes

notice there is nothing showing for dislikes.

If a bar has 5 likes and 1 dislike it will be proportional to the 150 dp SO:

likes   ---------------

dislikes---

THE PROBLEM IS that the textViews sometimes are right then randomly there wil be a false illustraion like the following:

likes = 10

dilikes = 0

likes    -------

dislikes ------------------

OR

likes - 0

dislikes - 0

likes    --------------------

dislikes ---------

SOLUTION:

```
if(dislikes_cnt < 1){
            dislikes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            dislikes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(likes_cnt < 1){
            likes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            likes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Instead of trying to set the widths to 1 or 0 when the likes were 0, or dislikes were 0. I instead set the view to GONE and VISIBLE accordingly and it all worked as I intended. Thanks for comments!

FINAL CODE:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View V = convertView;

        if(V == null){
            LayoutInflater vi =
                    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            V = vi.inflate(R.layout.barlist_row, null);

        }

        BarListItem ci = mBarList.get(position);
        long likes_cnt = ci.getLikes();
        long dislikes_cnt = ci.getDislikes();

        TextView likes = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.prg_likes);
        TextView dislikes = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.prg_dislikes);
        TextView title = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        TextView distance = (TextView)V.findViewById(R.id.txt_distance);

        if(likes_cnt > dislikes_cnt){
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            likes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
            px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150*((float)dislikes_cnt/(float)likes_cnt), r.getDisplayMetrics());
            dislikes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
        }else{
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            dislikes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
            px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,150*((float)likes_cnt/(float)dislikes_cnt), r.getDisplayMetrics());
            likes.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(px);
        }

        if(dislikes_cnt < 1){
            dislikes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            dislikes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(likes_cnt < 1){
            likes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            likes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        title.setText(ci.getTitle());
        likes.setText(" " + String.valueOf(ci.getLikes()));
        dislikes.setText(" " + String.valueOf(ci.getDislikes()));
        distance.setText(String.valueOf(ci.getDistance()) + " miles");

        return V;
    }
```

Comment: You can use a customized progress bar/Rating bar and pass your own images in the theme. Also because you are using a list adapter the views are re-used so make sure you reset all the textviews/imageviews in your getView() method.

Comment: It might be because you are not handling the cases where `likes == dislikes`. Check your if condition.

Comment: I tried another snippet of code in which I handled that condition and it made no difference. Thank you tho!

Comment: I attempted to use a progress bar but found the width idea I used quicker, and more dirty apparently. So for future applications or in the future of this application I will look into custom progres bars. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on "reset all images and textviews" plz cause I am not satified with how this is working yet